# facebook developers Platform Terms 6.a.i.1

Tags: facebook

FB said that I violated these one item, how can I modify it?

Platform Terms 6.a.i.1: You must always have in effect and maintain administrative, physical, and technical safeguards that do the following: Meet or exceed industry standards given the sensitivity of the Platform Data

Comment: _"You must have a publicly available way for people to report security vulnerabilities in your App to you"_ - guess that could be as simple as publishing an email address for such purposes somewhere in your terms/policy.

Comment: can you resolve ? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Im also encountered this. The problem is that i don't know why I'm getting this.

All i know that it related to this
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/data-security

I have a month deadline to figure this.
All my connection are secured.